# Redirect all subdomains to another file

Tags: .htaccess

My greetings to all.

I have a problem for which I am looking for a solution.
I have an my-website.com site and every user who registers on my site gets a personal link: **USERNAME.my-website.com** .

Meanwhile, I had the following rule in my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.my-website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) process.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

How to make all sub-domains ( **USERNAME.my-website.com** ) point to process.php ( **process.php/USERNAME** ) file and that the others urls like **my-website.com/OTHER** point to **index.php/USERNAME** ? ( **in case OTHER is not a file or a folder of my site** )
Here's what I did, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, you need one rewrite rule when you detect a subdomain and one rewrite rule pointing to the index file when the requested path does not resolve to a physical file or folder. Nothing special, nothing surprising. So what is your _actual_ question?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I would like to redirect all subdomains to a process.php file and the other urls to the index.php file.

Comment: Sure, we understand that from your question. Please note that there are many many existing answers so similar questions. Which you can use to start to implement your own solution. SO is not a free code writing service. We are here to offer help with _specific_ issues, when you have a detail you cannot sort out yourself. But we expect that you start yourself, that you attempt to implement your own solution. So why can't you implement the two rewriting rules considering that you already implemented one?

Comment: I just changed my question.
with more information.
Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

"But it doesn't work" is a bit vague, so all we can do is given some general advice and suggestions...

First you need to make sure that those subdomains are actually served at all by your http server. You did not write anything about that, nor how you host your site at all.

Also you obviously have to take care that distributed configuration files (".htaccess") are considered at all by your http server, also something which is not clear from your question.

Given both of those aspects you will indeed have to concentrate on your rewriting rules. Here is a variant of your own implementation with a few changes:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/process\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.my-website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /process.php/%1 [QSA,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php/?
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,END]
```

You probably will have to make some more changes. But based on the vague information you gave it is hard to be more specific.

A good way to start debugging issues with rewriting is to enable rewrite logging inside your http server. That allows to closely monitor what is actually happening inside your rewriting engine. Please consult the documentation about that: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html